# Diameter Distortion though edge removal

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose we are given a graph $G((V,E)$ with $diam(G)=d$. It can be shown that removing a single edge $e=\{u, v\}$ the diameter of the generated graph $G'=(V, E\setminus\{e\})$ is at most $2d$. A cycle of length $(2d+1)$ would be an example this upper bound, for if we remove a single edge from a cycle of length $(2d+1)$ the endpoints of the removed edge will be at distance $2d$, whereas the diameter of a cycle is $\lfloor \frac{|C|}{2}\rfloor$.

I am wondering how much the diameter of a graph can be distorted if I repeatedly remove edges. Is there a graph $G$ with initial diameter $d$ from which I can repeatedly remove edges and double the diameter at each step? That is, if I remove $f$ edges the generated graph has diameter $2^fd$? Or is there another known upper bound?

In the case the graph gets disconnected, then what is the maximum diameter any of the generated connected components may have?

Comment: Is the concept of "diameter" defined if a graph is not connected?

Comment: You can either assume the graph remains connected, or otherwise, I would be interested in the maximal diameter of the connected components